# Google consent automatic accepting

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am new newbie to Selenium Driver. I am trying to click 'Agree' button automatically on google search pop up using selenium driver interface. I am using python and the code is:

```
driver.get(f"https://www.google.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]').click()
```

But this is not working. Can someone help me?[google auto pop up for consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSrUo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars') #attempting to disable infobar
browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=options, 
executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 
'consent.google.com')]")) 
time.sleep(5) 
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span').click() 

browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//form //div[@role = 'button' and @id = 
'introAgreeButton'").click()
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it; never just post code on its own.